# I want to place a fixed background behind absolute positioned Images using css

Tags: html, css, css-position

On the very front, when the page loads, I want to show some images scattered around but with the fixed background. Thus, when the user scrolls, the rest of the body rolls up like normal having a background color and everything else. I have seen this on a lot of websites so I am guessing it's rather easy to do, but I can't cause I'm a noob.
Really appreciate any help.

heres the html for images

```
<div class="front bg" style="border:5px dashed black;">
    <img id="dp" src="images/dp.jpg" alt="Face Up Front">
    <img id="finger-face" src="images/gall12.jpg" alt="Finger Face">
    <img id="with-friend" src="images/gall19.jpg" alt="With Friend">
</div>
```

heres the css i tried

```
 .bg{
    background-image: url('images/showoff.jpg');
    background-size:100vw 100vh;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    position:relative;
}

#dp{
    width:16%;
    height:auto;
    position:absolute;
    top:15%;
    right:8%;
    border-radius: 30px;
}

#finger-face{
    width: 15%;
    height:auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 55%;
    left: 8%;
}

#with-friend{
    width: 30%;
    height:auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 25%;
    left: 35%;
    border-radius: 30px;
    box-shadow: -1px -1px 6px 0px #ff0000;
}
```

EDIT: After spending the whole night grinding through this mess, I came across something that my intuition tells me is not a very professional and long term fix but this is the tutorial that did it for me. I added the `background-attachment:fixed` property in the `bg` styles.

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_full_page

I actually wanna know if this is a professional and a practical solution. And I have no idea what role `html{height:100%; margin:0;}` has to play. So I would appreciate any suggestions or comments.

Comment: Do you have an example of what you want?

Comment: sorry I can't really comment on your question (since I don't have sufficient reputation) and I don't really understand your question. But I do believe you need import something like [ScrollMagic](http://scrollmagic.io/) to handle the "animation" for you. Please check out the example over [here](http://scrollmagic.io/examples/advanced/advanced_tweening.html) under the last sample. They do have sample source code which may help you even if you're new into it. UPDATE: Typo.

Comment: @TheDev Like here: https://www.google.com/drive/

Comment: Why would you think `background-attachment` is not "professional"? Does it work? If so, I don't see an issue using a standard CSS property.

Answer (score 1):

If i understand you right you want a parallax effect. With css alone there is only one solution: `background-attachment:fixed`

This has the down side of not working currectly on some mobile devices.

However if you are willing to use third party libarys and a bit of javascript there are some good solutions already out there

[parallax.js](http://pixelcog.github.io/parallax.js/)
[Stellar.js](http://markdalgleish.com/projects/stellar.js/)

to name a few. Google will grand you more. As of its professional and practical use, is see no problems with either of them.

Answer (score 0):

Use `background-attachment: scroll` or `background-attachment: local` rather than `background-attachment: fixed`